# Why is an error message output instead of starting an executable in subdirectory of batch file directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

An error message is output when I try to start "launcher.exe" located in `anylocation\ffa\` with this command:

```
start \ffa\launcher.exe
```

Batch script should have access to file because stored on disk like this:

```
ANYLOCATION/myprogram.bat
ANYLOCATION/ffa/launcher.exe
```

If I type

```
start /ffa/launcher.exe
```

output is: `invalid switch`

But if I type

```
start \ffa\launcher.exe
```

output is `system cannot find file`

Which mistake to I made on starting `launcher.exe`?

Comment: Use back instead of forward slash. Is there a FFA directory in the root directory ? Try to specify .\ffa if you need a relative path

Comment: @Marged is right, you're looking for `start .\ffa\launcher.exe`, or just `start ffa\launcher.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%~dp0
```

is your batch file directory. So

```
%~dp0\ffa\launcher.exe
```

There is no need to use start.

## Starting a Program

See start /? and call /? for help on all three ways.

### Specify a program name

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### Use Start command

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

### Use Call command

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

Comment: Perfect first impression ;-)

Comment: Wow! But i made something like this so it doesn't need to start on opening of program, it needs to start when i select that server..Because i tried to make it in java and c# but its to complicated, soooo...I choose batch...I did something like this(this is my code): [link](http://pastebin.com/SvNESS31)

Comment: Just type this in your batch and enclose with quotes if path contains spaces. `"%~dp0\ffa\launcher.exe"`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: Some notes to complete the answer and explain why `\ffa\launcher.exe` failed at all. `.\ffa\launcher.exe` or `ffa\launcher.exe` starts executable in subdirectory `ffa` of __current directory__. `..\ffa\launcher.exe` starts executable in subdirectory `ffa` of __parent directory__ of current directory. `\ffa\launcher.exe` starts executable in subdirectory `ffa` of __root of current drive__.

Comment: \ffa\launcher.exe failed because launcher.exe launches ogar.exe( [link](https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar) ), so ogar.exe requires config file or it will make its own...Soo, when i start \ffa\ogar.exe it wont work or, if i start \ffa\launcher.exe it wont work...So i made out with making NEW batch file that tells launcher.exe to start, but diffrence its that this new batch file its in ffa\ :) So it tells ogar.exe to open in \ffa so it has own config and no need for new one :)

Comment: `cd %~dp0` will change directory. See `cd /?`.